# Is it possible to do CSRF for POST request with an XML body

Tags: csrf

I am testing an application that send XML data as body in POST request. The application is not using any CSRF token
Is there any way to perform CSRF in this case. XHR does not works in latest browsers, as it blocks CORS requests.
One link i came across but is not working. 
http://pentestmonkey.net/blog/csrf-xml-post-request
Any way to achieve this?

Comment: There are many questions on this site that discuss issues along these lines.  This answer will probably help: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/166798/149676

Comment: Do you require a particular `Content-Type` or just an XML-formatted body?

Comment: Yes, it requires Content-type as text/xml only. If it was accepting any content-type, text/plain would have worked,

Comment: you can't use POST from a CSRF alone. Unless the server allows GET you need XSS to do it via ajax...